# Что делать, если случайно поставил редирект админки WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, редирект

Что делать, если случайно поставил редирект админки WordPress в настройках "общие" и теперь при попытке войти в админку меня редиректит на несуществующую страницу? При попытке зайти в админку добавляется в середину адресной строки "/cars/" и попытка входа невозможна, чтобы откатить назад:
http://mysite.by/cars/wp-login.php

Comment: http://mysite.by/ - это не WordPress сайт

Comment: Это пример адреса.

Comment: Настройки постоянных ссылок на этой странице `http://test.kagg.eu/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` на админку не влияют никак. Почему у вас вопрос отмечен тэгом `.htaccess`?

Comment: Простите, настройки "Общие".

Answer (score 1):

Только напрямую через SQL базу данных в таблице wp_options в site_url или скопировав всю папку админки вордпресса wp-admin в соответствующую директорию, например "/cars/". Может, поможет кому-нибудь при таком же косяке или при переносе админки на другой адрес.

Comment: Значит, не в настройках постоянных ссылок было дело, как я и говорил

Comment: После правки вопроса ответ поддерживаю.